Sum over a countable set
Suppose $a$ is a function from $\Omega$ (Countably infinite) to $[0, \infty)$, I try to understand the summation over $\Omega$.
The definition is given as,
$\sum_\Omega a(\omega) = \sup (\sum_F a(\omega)$ : F is a finite subset of $\Omega).$
It makes sense, but can I define it in other ways?
For example, since $\Omega $ is countably infinite, there is a bijection between $\Bbb{N}$ and $\Omega$, so I can order the element of it in someway to get a traditional series, since all the terms are non-negative, I can rearrange in any way and the sum remains the same (finite or $\infty$).

That would be perfectly fine, and it's probably the easiest to match up with your basic intuition from calculus. The supremum definition is moreso meant to try to account for uncountable sets.
So, if we have $\Omega$, we can find a bijection $a : \mathbb{N} \to \Omega$ and hence write $\Omega = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots\}$, and then
$$
\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \omega
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n
$$
I recommend cross-checking it with your definition, e.g. show that the above definition holds iff the supremum definition does.

But this definition may not be useful in checking some properties of summation? For example, I need to show the monotone convergence. $\text{(Convergence monotone)} \quad \text{For each integer } n, , a_n : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^+ \text{ is a positive function. It is assumed that for each } \omega \in \Omega, , \text{the sequence } a_n(\omega) \text{ is increasing, and we denote its limit by } a(\omega). \text{ We then have:}
[
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{\Omega} a_n(\omega) = \sum_{\Omega} a(\omega).
]$
